# Using datetime in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a date time item in a list  that I want to interact with. I access the items in the list via SPListItem.
[image]

My code:

```
_relevantDate = (DateTime)_siteInfo["cimKeyDocumentDate"];
```

What the code means in terms of types etc:

```
[datetime property] = [datetime cast]SPListItem[field name];
```

I'm aware of the SPFieldDateTime type but I can't see a type it returns and I am confused at how I should do return the datetime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code would return `datetime` type after correct casting.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myListItem["MyDateField"].ToString());
```

but if you want to use `SPFieldDateTime` then you will have to write it like

```
SPFieldDateTime myDateTime =(SPFieldDateTime)web.Fields[FieldNames.DateFieldName];
```

This will return a field that contains date and time values.See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielddatetime_members.aspx).

Comment: That was what my code looked like originally but an exception gets thrown. I changed it to your code (with the relevant names) "String reference not set to an instance of a String".

Comment: "MyDateField" should be  replaced by your datetime field  internal name.It should work.